# Show equality about composition of permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

Let $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\pi\in \text{Sym}(n)$. For $1\leq k\in \mathbb{N}$ we define $\pi^{-n}:=\left (\pi^n\right )^{-1}$.

Show for all $k,\ell\in \mathbb{Z}$ the equation $\pi^k\circ \pi^{\ell}=\pi^{k+\ell}$.

$$$$

Since $\pi^{-n}$ is defined I suppose that we have to show first the above equality for natural exponents, right?

But how exactly can we show that? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: You seem to have garbled some of your variables. The second sentence introduces $k$ but then instead uses the $n$ that was previously the index of the symmetric group. I suspect you mean $\pi^{-k}:=(\pi^k)^{-1}$?

Comment: In this sort of question, where you're trying to prove an elementary fact that's usually taken for granted, you should explain which results or definitions you want to use and which not. This could be proved from all sorts of things, but when you're proving something this elementary, you typically don't want to prove it from certain basics.

Comment: Do we apply induction on $k$ and on $\ell$ ? @joriki

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me why you think I'd reply to your comments if you ignore mine.

Comment: As I have understand your comments we have to use the definitions and some properties to prove that. Or have I understood that wrong? But to show that it holds for all $k,\ell\in \mathbb{Z}$ do we use induction? Or which is the idea we have to follow? @joriki

Answer (score 1):

Consider the statement
$$\tag{$\Phi_\ell$} \forall k\in\Bbb Z\colon \pi^k\circ \pi ^\ell=\pi^{k+\ell}.$$
As $\pi^0=\operatorname{id}$, we know that $\Phi_0$ is true.

By the recursive definition of power, $$\tag1\pi^{k+1}=\pi^k\circ \pi=\pi\circ \pi^k$$
holds at least for integers $k\ge 0$. From this $\pi^{k}=\pi\circ \pi^{k-1}$ for $k\ge 1$;  by taking inverses, $\pi^{-k}=\pi^{1-k}\circ \pi^{-1}$; by rearranging $\pi^{-k}\circ \pi=\pi^{-k+1}$. Together, this shows that $\Phi_1$ holds.

If $\Phi_{\ell_1}$ and $\Phi_{\ell_2}$ are true, then so is $\Phi_{\ell_1+\ell_2}$: 
$$ \pi^k\circ \pi^{\ell_1+\ell_2}\stackrel{\Phi_{\ell_2}}= \pi^k\circ (\pi^{\ell_1}\circ \pi^{\ell_2})\stackrel{ass.}=(\pi^k\circ \pi^{\ell_1})\circ \pi^{\ell_2}\stackrel{\Phi_{\ell_1}}=\pi^{k+\ell_1}\circ\pi^{\ell_2}\stackrel{\Phi_{\ell_2}}= \pi^{k+\ell_1+\ell_2}.$$

If $\Phi_\ell$ is true, then so is $\Phi_{-\ell}$:
$$ \pi^k\circ \pi^{-\ell}=\pi^k\circ(\pi^\ell)^{-1}=\pi^{(k-\ell)+\ell}\circ(\pi^\ell)^{-1}=\pi^{k-\ell}\circ\pi^{\ell}\circ(\pi^\ell)^{-1}=\pi^{k-\ell}$$

From the above, we conclude that $\{\,\ell\in\Bbb Z\mid \Phi_\ell\,\}$ is closed under addition and additive inverses and contains $1$. Then it must be all of $\Bbb Z$, as desired

Comment: So we apply induction on $\ell$, or not?

Comment: At your proof we show that the set of the numbers that satisfy the statement is equal to the set of integers, right? So we assume the part of k holds, right?